# Waiting for response after clickling

Tags: node.js, ajax, google-chrome, puppeteer

I click on button, and which send ajax request and change input hidden value.
How can I wait for an answer and trace the change of the hidden field?

I had tried make "sleep" and get events, but sometimes you get bad data, because the request is very long.

```
http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
if (req.url === '/') {
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
            'cache-control': 'public,max-age=31536000',
        });
        res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/templates/index.html'));
        return;
    } else if (req.method === 'POST') {

        let body = '';
        await req.on('data', (data) => body += data);

        body = qs.parse(body);

        let url = body.url;

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);

        let count = (selector) => page.evaluate((selector) => {
            return (document.querySelectorAll(selector)).length;
        }, selector);

        let sleep = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

        const countM = await count(MSEL),
            countS = await count(SSEL);
        console.log(countS, countM);

        let click = (selector, number) => page.click(`${selector}:nth-child(${number})`);

        let data = [];

        for (let i = 1; i <= countS; i++) {
            await click(SSEL, i);
            sleep(SLEEP);

            for (let j = 1; j <= countM; j++) {
                await click(MSEL, j);
                sleep(SLEEP);

                const info = await page.evaluate(() => {
                    return {
                        val: document.getElementById('val').value,
                        cc: document.getElementById('cc').value
                    };
                });
                data.push(info);
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    res.writeHead(400, {
        'content-type': 'text/plain',
    });
    res.end('Something is wrong. Missing URL.');
    return;
}
}).listen(3000);
```

Sorry for my english.
Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the code you have?

Comment: In this case, look in to callbacks. Callbacks are functions that are called once a process, like an AJAX call, have finished.

Comment: Now I'm done through a delay
 await click(SELECTOR, j);
                    console.log("Sleep");
                    sleep(SLEEP);
                    const info = await page.evaluate(() => { ... . I did not find the desired function with a callback

Comment: That is a bad and unreliable solution. Can you please show us your code?

Comment: Please provide some more information. I have some questions, what is MSEL? What is SSEL? What is the URL? What is in the templates/index.html? What kind of bad data you get? Why you are looping inside a loop? Why you have a sleep() promise but not awaiting that promise? What happens when you push info to the data, do you return it as response?

Answer (score 0):

I could ask you a lot of questions before answering,

- what is MSEL and SSEL?
- What is the URL?
- What is in the templates/index.html?
- What kind of bad data you get?
- Why you are looping inside a loop?
- Why you have a sleep() promise but not awaiting that promise?
- What happens when you push info to the data, do you return it as response?

etc etc. the list can go on, but we have to start somewhere, right? I will not write the whole code, and do everything for you. But I'll help you understand the problem.

Lots of part in your code is missing, as well as there are errors because you did not write things properly.

I'd separate the functions. I'm assuming you have the variables called MSEL, SSEL somewhere defined.

First, you are not returning anything in response. That's something you need to watch for, if you are not returning response, then the request is never going to end, and result in timeout.

```
http
  .createServer(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.url === "/") {
      if (req.method === "GET") {
        res.writeHead(200, {
          "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
          "cache-control": "public,max-age=31536000"
        });
        res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/templates/index.html"));
        return;
      } else if (req.method === "POST") {
        let body = "";
        await req.on("data", data => (body += data));
        body = qs.parse(body);
        const returnData = await getData({ body, MSEL, SSEL }); // <-- seperate the function
        res.end(returnData); // <-- return the data
      }
    } else {
      res.writeHead(400, {
        "content-type": "text/plain"
      });
      res.end("Something is wrong. Missing URL.");
      return;
    }
  })
  .listen(3000);
```

And here is the function seperately, notice how I wrote await before sleep and also refactored some bits and parts a little bit, also returning the function after everything is done.

```
async function getData({ body, MSEL, SSEL }) {
  let url = body.url;

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  let count = selector =>
    page.evaluate(selector => {
      return document.querySelectorAll(selector).length;
    }, selector);

  let sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  const countM = await count(MSEL),
    countS = await count(SSEL);

  let click = (selector, number) =>
    page.click(`${selector}:nth-child(${number})`);

  let data = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= countS; i++) {
    await click(SSEL, i);
    await sleep(SLEEP);

    for (let j = 1; j <= countM; j++) {
      await click(MSEL, j);
      await sleep(SLEEP);

      const info = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return {
          val: document.getElementById("val").value,
          cc: document.getElementById("cc").value
        };
      });
      data.push(info);
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

What I did was refactor and fix your code a bit, but this is not the solution you are looking for, the code might not even work.

You need to understand how promises works. Refer to the following tutorials before copy-pasting my solution hoping that it'll work ;) ,

- https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-promises-in-depth
- https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await